# Extract polygons of PNG with GdalOgrInJava

Tags: gdal, geojson, java, polygonize, png

I have *PNG* pictures with **polygons** of different colours on them. What I plan to do is to extract these **Polygons** using the **polygonize** function (see [here](http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/gdal.html#Polygonize%28org.gdal.gdal.Band,%20org.gdal.gdal.Band,%20org.gdal.ogr.Layer,%20int%29))
Then I will try to encode the **polygons** in *GeoJSON* (maybe using [this](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html)? Or is there also a java tool for that?)

I am quite new to GIS so I don't quite understand how to use the **polygonize** function mentioned above. I don't know which of the three **polygonize** functions I have to use.

I have very simple *PNGs* with some polygons on it. Would someone please show me a code snippet of how to use **polygonize** function with regard to my problem?